# Impossible to install Nvidia driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

Sorry, I have to put logs in the comments but askubuntu sees them as spam.
I have integrated Intel and Nvidia GeForce940MX and it's impossible to install drivers for it.
I got:
ubuntu-drivers devices
(in comments)

So I ran autoinstall and I got the driver and the message about Secure Boot agreed and did a reboot (note that I didn't have to write in a password after reboot, although the message told me that we'll be necessary).
So after reboot and everything I ran ubuntu-drivers devices again, and again got the same message like on the beginning, that the geforce needs the drivers. So I run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455` and got

```
nvidia-driver-455 is already the newest version
```

So I checked if the card is visible and ran `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
cat cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa4320000 IRQ 139
```

But it shows only integrated Intel card.
When I run `Nvidia-settings` I have an option to the set-prime card and I can choose between Intel and Nvidia. So I chose Nvidia. However, on the console the is the message:
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

I also ran prime-select Nvidia and it tells me that "Info: the Nvidia profile is already set", although the system doesn't see the Nvidia card! Also, when I run `nvidia-smi` it shows:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
the ubuntu-drivers list gives:
(in comments)

I have no idea what is going on. Ubuntu is 18.04.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ubuntu-drivers list:
nvidia-driver-410
nvidia-driver-455
nvidia-driver-450
nvidia-driver-450-server
nvidia-driver-415
nvidia-driver-440-server
nvidia-driver-418-server
nvidia-driver-390

Comment: ubuntu-drivers devices:
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Dsv000017AAsd000039CEbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free